# How to convert text into greek letters

Tags: javascript, string-conversion, transliteration

Can anyone tell me how to convert input text into greek letters?

**Explanation:** 
I want to convert text which I type in input box into greek letters. Please help me out.

```
<input type="text" id="my_text">
<p id="output"></>
<button onclick="greek()">Now</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function greek() {
    var text = document.getElementById("my_text").value;
    ?
    ?
    ?
}
```

Here I don't know what to do ??

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: Cause I am working on app in which i need.

Comment: Note that "J" and "V" have no direct conversions to Greek.

Comment: @CoderMe Please don't modify your original question if you have a new issue to solve - the original question with its original answers might still be useful to future readers! Consider rolling back your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define how your latin input text shall be transliterated into the greek alphabet. See e. g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Greek for possible transliteration tables.

You would then create a JavaScript map from the chosen table:

```
let transliteration = {"a": "α", "b": "β", ... }
```

To perform the actual transliteration, you will need to write a function

```
function transliterate(string) {
  var result = "";
  for (chr of string) {
    result += (transliteration[chr] || "_");
  }
  return result;
}
```

For non-transliteratable characters, placeholder "_" will be returned.

If you chose a transliteration scheme which contains bigrams ("ai") or trigrams ("nch"), you could employ a regex:

```
let transliteration = {"a": "α", "ai": "αι", "av": "αυ", "v": "β", "g": "γ", ...};
let result = string.replace(/ai|av|ng|a|v|g|.../g, chr => transliteration[chr]);
```

Comment: <input type="text" id="my_text"></input>
 <button onclick="transliterate()">Go</button>
 <p id="output"></p>


<script type="text/javascript">

let transliteration = {"a": "α", "b": "β", "c":"X"};

function transliterate() {
  var string= document.getElementById("my_text").value;
  var result = "";
  for (chr of string) {
    result += (transliteration[chr] || "_");
  }
  document.getElementById("output").value = result;
}
 its not working

Comment: its Not Working le_m . Now What ??

Comment: Now you would analyze the error, look at the error message if any, and try to debug your code. Hint: Not all HTML elements have a 'value' attribute.

Comment: No error in console le_m . its weird .

Comment: @CoderMe Your code doesn't have a syntax error => no console error. But you have another problem: you assign the result to the "value" attribute of a `<p>` element. But a `<p>` element doesn't have such attribute. Try "textContent" instead.

Comment: i enter abc in text field and it gives me Î±Î²X this result. i use textContent instead value

Comment: @CoderMe then you have another issue: do you use utf-8 encoding for your html document?  - Also, please ask in the comments only or create a new question for such issues instead of modifying your existing one!

Comment: its working Thank You Sooo Much @le_m

Comment: Yeah Sure Why Not .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that..:

```
function greek(letter){
  switch(letter){
    case 'q':
     return ";"
    break;
    case 'w':
     return "ς"
    break;
    case 'e':
     return "ς"
    break;
    case 'r':
     return "ε"
    break;
    case 't':
     return "ρ"
    break;
    case 'y':
     return "τ"
    break;
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through the the letters and covert them with a case statement or other similar operation.

example:

```
function greek(){
  var text= document.getElementById("my_text").value;
  var output = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    switch(text[i]){
      case ' ':
        output += ' ';
        break;
      case 'a':
        output += 'α';
        break;
      case 'b':
        output += 'ß';
      // ... And so forth
      default:
        console.log("Unrecognized character");
        break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
```

Edited to output to `<p>`.

Comment: Let Me try This dlsso .

Comment: its not working. error occurred

Comment: Please state the error. Also, note that keeping the transliteration in an object like le_m suggested would be the preferred method. The switch is just to give you an idea of the process that needs to happen.

Comment: No error occurred in console but it can't show any output .

Comment: Looks like you made output a `p`. I'll adjust.

Comment: it show Î±ÃŸ this type of output

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Make sure you have `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in your html.